# Find out last activity of Service Account Key in GCP IAM

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-iam

Is it possible to know the last activity of service account's key in GCP IAM, similar to AWS IAM's [GetAccessKeyLastUsed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetAccessKeyLastUsed.html)? I was avoiding the option of monitoring the activity from GCP Stackdriver.

Comment: I hope that I am wrong with my comment. I am not aware of any 100% sure method. Service Accounts can access multiple projects / organizations. You would need to combine Audit Logging with Stackdriver and have access to the same resources (projects / organizations). This would be expensive and compute / data intensive. A service account can have multiple keys. I do not believe that individual keys are even tracked in GCP. One of my specialties is Google Security so I am very interested in an authoritative answer to this question.

Comment: @JohnHanley yeah I also come to the same conclusion as yours. But do you know if it is possible to know the last activity of the service account itself?

Comment: I do not know of a way to access the last usage of a service account based upon my previous comment or any API. The key to a service account is the Private Key. This is used to sign a JWT. The JWT is exchanged for an Access Token. The Access Token is used to Authorize access. The tracking should be easy. The problem that I see for Google is that every access would need to be logged for every API, for every service, for every connection and the volume of data would be huge. You would need to pay for the storage of that data (nothing is really free in the cloud - costs are just moved around).

Comment: @JohnHanley that means it will be better to analyze it from stackdriver if it is not possible from the API itself where the logs are stored in the bucket or published with pub/sub

Comment: I don't have a better comment than my previous comments. Note that I said Audit Logging plus Stackdriver plus access to all accounts / organizations that the service account can access. I do not think that Google designed into their system a method to answer your question. I might be wrong and that is why I posted my first comment - hoping another expert will comment.

Comment: based on this doc it says "Audit service accounts and keys using either the serviceAccount.keys.list() method or the Logs Viewer page in the console." You can try to create a service account then execute some scripts to test and check the audit logs in the Stackdriver logging if there's an entry. I haven't tried it due to lack of time.

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts

Comment: @Christopher it is exactly like the previous comments and my initial idea, but I am trying to avoid that and hopefully there could be a API call that will show it similar to AWS IAM API

Comment: There is an IAM API but the method your looking seems not yet available. You might want to file a feature request or search for an existing feature for this one.

https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts
https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys
https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests

Comment: To me, this is basic, required, functionality. Very surprised there is no "last login" field in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cloud Monitoring metrics [1] to monitor `service account` or `service account key` usage.

You can identify unused service accounts and keys by [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-monitoring
[2] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-monitoring#identify-unused

Answer (score 0):

You now have that feature on the Policy Analyzer. Currently, it can only be used via console, `gcloud` and API REST:

1. **Console**: IAM & Admin > Policy Analyzer > Analyze recent activity > When was the last time this service account was used? [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz9Qo.png)
2. **Comand line**: `gcloud policy-intelligence query-activity` ([Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/policy-intelligence/query-activity))
3. **API REST**: Out of the box for cURL and PowerShell. I guess you can use the discovery build library to impement it on code, but I don't try it yet. ([Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/policy-intelligence/docs/activity-analyzer-service-account-authentication#iam-view-service-account-recent-usage-activity-analyzer-rest))